# How to diagnose why added element disappears

Tags: javascript, jquery

**jquery-3.1.0**

This script adds "blablabla". But after that the page reloads.
So, the added element disappears.

When I stop in the debugger (the brekapoint is in the code), "blablabla" is vaisible, then I make step and occur somewhere in the middle of jQuery. I tried to show you where I occur.

I have removed all irrelevant scripts, but still can't localize the problem.

And of course I can't model it in jsfiddle.

Could you give me a kick here?

```
<script>

    function show_frame_person_create_get(){
        $("#people").after("blablabla");
        debugger;
    }


    function init_frame_person_create(){
        var person_create_button = $('#person_create');

        person_create_button.click(show_frame_person_create_get);
    }

    init_frame_person_create();

</script>


jQuery.event = {
...
    dispatch: function( nativeEvent ) {
        // Determine handlers
        handlerQueue = jQuery.event.handlers.call( this, event, handlers 
                    ret = ( ( jQuery.event.special[ handleObj.origType ] || {} ).handle ||
                        handleObj.handler ).apply( matched.elem, args );

                    if ( ret !== undefined ) { // I OCCUR HERE!
);
```

Comment: can you provide fiddle

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/qx839j7k/12/ But fiddle can't show anything here.

Comment: Can you show graphically what is happening and what you want..?

Comment: are you asking why your page is reloading? Or are you asking why the element disappears? The element disappears because the page is re-loaded, obviously. But why the page re-loads is not clear from the code you've posted so far

Comment: Is $('#person_create') by chance a button? What happens if you add a preventDefault() to show_frame_person_create_get

Comment: What do you mean that "I occur here"? I mean, you're a person, not code, so I would expect you to be an ongoing, continuous occurrence (depending on your philosophical background, of course). Does an error occur at that point in the code? Does the reload occur there? Does the element disappear?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to have a $(document).ready() function to put the string on the document. You also need to have a Jquery library.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('body').append('blahblah')
})
```